# Octave: How to sum(A .* B, 3) without expanding A .* B?

Tags: octave

Consider the following scenario, for A with size [k, 1, m] and B with size [1, n, m], how can one get the same result as:

```
C = sum(A .* B, 3);
```

without expanding

```
A .* B
```

Because that takes way too much memory.
Something like the following loop but natively:

```
C = zeros(k,n);
for idx = 1:m
    C += A(:,1,idx) * B(1,:,idx);
end
```

I guess I could also ask if there's a function like bsxfun with a "reduce"-like behavior?
Something like:

```
C = bsxfun_accumulate(@(a, b) a * b, A, B);
```

Note: by native I mean cs/cuda code-paths, or opencl code-path, or x86-sse, or plain x86 instructions. Whatever is available.

Comment: What do you mean by "but natively"? Loops are native to MATLAB, and [not necessarily slow](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/02/12/run-code-faster-with-the-new-matlab-execution-engine/). You just need to use `C = C + ...` rather than `+=` which isn't valid MATLAB syntax.

Comment: In addition to what Wolfie said, you also want to use `*` (matrix multiplication) instead of `.*` (element-wise multiplication) in your for loop.

Comment: By native I mean machine code. x86 or gpu code, definitely not interpreted. I changed the title to Octave only as my impression is that Matlab was much slower than octave. Is Matlab running on jvm or machine code?

Comment: Thanks @gnovice I updated the loop code.

Comment: @hackdev I doubt MATLAB is slower than octave. Recent JIT compilers of MATLAB  make it run as fast as native code. Also most of the operations (such as `.*`) are not run in MATLAB code, but in the underlying Fotran accelerated multi-threaded inbuilt function. MATLAB is fast for matrix operations, almost unbeatable fast. It also has the option of running most of the basic operations on the GPU.

Comment: If Octave was faster than MATLAB, The MathWorks would go out of business... I don't understand why this is your assumption?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can actually solve your problem by simply [reshaping](https://octave.org/doc/interpreter/Rearranging-Matrices.html#index-reshape) the variables `A` and `B` and applying a [matrix multiply](https://octave.org/doc/interpreter/Arithmetic-Ops.html#index-mtimes):

```
C = reshape(A, [], m)*(reshape(B, [], m).');
```

Basically, summing the results of `m` sets of multiplications involving `k`-by-1 column vectors and 1-by-`n` row vectors is the equivalent of multiplying a `k`-by-`m` matrix of your columns and an `m`-by-`n` matrix of your rows.

Comment: Gee, that not only seems to work, it's actually ridiculously fast compared to the loop. I would give you two votes, but I can only vote once. XD

Comment: @hackdev as asker of the question, you can mark the answer as "accepted", thereby closing the question and awarding 1.5x the reputation points of an upvote.

Comment: I was having issues with this question because I have a corner case where A is [k, 1, 1], where matrix multiplication doesn't work. So I realized that .* always works. But in practice it explodes for large matrices. Basically adding an if size(A,3)==1 solves the whole issue. :)

Comment: @hackdev: If you are faced with a case where `A` is size `[k 1 1]` but `B` is still size `[1 n m]`, here's one way to solve it like above: `C = repmat(A, 1, m)*(reshape(B, [], m).');`

Comment: That last corner case works well by using `A * sum(B')`, but I'll measure to see which is faster.

Comment: @hackdev: Nice simplification, but I think it should be `A*sum(B, 3)`.

Comment: Ok, it seems that `C = repmat(A, 1, m)*(reshape(B, [], m).');` is as fast as `A * sum(B')` which are both about 10x slower than `A * sum(B,2)'` for something like `m = 10000` - assuming B already reshaped.